# Text and Animation

Tags: java, android, eclipse, animation, text

Eh, I want to show my text after the animation has played. In this code, it executes both the animation and the text at the same time, so how do I wait till after the animation has played all the way through to show the text? Or how do I hide the text until the animation has played?

```
package com.example.magic8ballers;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Magic8Ballers extends Activity {
    MediaPlayer song; //song reference
    TextView answer; // TextView reference
    Button button; // Button reference
    Magic8BallersCode m8b; // M8B reference
    // Animation object
    Animation an;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_magic8_ballers);

        // associate answer with TextView object with id textView1
        answer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        // associate button with Button object with id button
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setText("Shake It!");
        //Create new Magic8Ball object
        m8b = new Magic8BallersCode();
        song = MediaPlayer.create(Magic8Ballers.this, R.raw.magic);


        //Shake it button animation
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);//reference to the        
        button that shakes it and provides prediction
        final ImageView imgView =
                (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);//reference to the animation image

        //Music Buttons                                                     
        Button btnSound = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);//reference to the 
        button that turns on the song
        Button btnSound2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);//reference to the     
        button that turns off the song

        //Animation
        final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(Magic8Ballers.this,
                R.anim.animation);

        //Button for animation
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                imgView.startAnimation(an);
                String prediction = m8b.getAnswer();
                // Set the label's text with the new prediction
                answer.setText(prediction);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `setAnimationListener method`. "An animation listener receives notifications from an animation. Notifications indicate animation related events, such as the end or the repetition of the animation." -- "developer.android.com".

- **Example:**

  ```
   an.setAnimationListener( new AnimationListener()

  { 

      public void onAnimationStart(Aninmation a){
           //Notifies the start of the animation.
        }

      public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation a){
          //Notifies the repetition of the animation.
         }

      public void onAnimationEnd(Animation a){
          //Notifies the end of the animation.
          //show your text here
      }

  });
  ```

Comment: Would I add the listener under the OnClick method where my animation already is?

Comment: You can setAnimationListener with your animation before onClick method. An animation listener receives notifications from an animation. When you call startAnimation(), AnimationListener "listen" for you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add an animation listener:

```
an.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {


                // ADD YOU TEXT HERE
            }
        });
```

after the animation finishes playing the listener adds your text.